# how to analyze Query CPU time

Tags: mysql, innodb, cpu-usage

How can I analyze the CPU time consumed by my Innodb queries?

I have innotop, but I cant seems to find where it is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may analyze CPU usage by individual queries with [SHOW PROFILE CPU](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-profiles.html) command

AFAIK there is no way to check how much CPU "all innodb queries used".

Comment: +1 although do note that SHOW PROFILE CPU is not accurate.  It uses a system call (getrusage()) which is only accurate to the process.  It's noted on the page you linked to.